# ECharts only shows the line between the two points inside the zoomed-in part in a line chart

Tags: javascript, echarts

When zooming in a line chart, it will only show the line between the two points inside the zoomed-in part like in below images (1st is original and 2nd is zoomed-in). Is this because I'm using a line type? I tried using scatter but I couldn't find an option to show a line like other libraries' scatterline. How can I show the line in and out of the zoomed window? Below is ECharts js code and here is [the example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/470snphe/).

[image: original]
[image: zoomed-in]

```
option = {
    xAxis: {},
    yAxis: {},
    toolbox: {
                left: 'center',
                feature: {
                    dataZoom: {
                        yAxisIndex: 'none'
                    },
                    restore: {},
                    saveAsImage: {}
                }
            },    
    series: [{
        //symbolSize: 20,
        data: [
            [0.0, 2.26],
            [4.0, 4.26],
            [5.0, 5.68],
            [6.0, 7.24],            
            [7.0, 4.82],            
            [8.0, 6.95],
            [9.0, 8.81],
            [10.0, 8.04],
            [11.0, 8.33],
            [12.0, 10.84],            
            [13.0, 7.58],
            [14.0, 9.96]
        ],
        type: 'line'
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that right understand what you want to desired output. Each library is on its own and all have different ways of presenting data... Can you draw what you need?

You want to get rid of line paddings?

```js
var option = {
  //...
  dataZoom: {
    yAxisIndex: 'none',
    filterMode: 'none' // <-- add this
  },
  //...
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant if I want to plot xy data, I can use a scatter chart which doesn't have a line option as far as I know. The other option is to use a line chart with xaxis type "value". With the latter, if I zoom in, the line get disconnected from points outside the zoomed-in region which is the issue here. I think it's a bug and reported it in their github page.

Comment: `[...] scatter chart which doesn't have a line option as far as I know`: You can use the different series together with the same axes if the data does not require a normal and logarithmic scales at the same time. `[...] the line get disconnected from points outside the zoomed-in region`: Is the answer above does not solve the problem?